# Access Graph API from native iOS application to create a user

Tags: ios, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I want to gain access to the Graph API in order to integrate a native iOS Sign Up page. I was able to achieve a native implementation of Sign In using ROPC but there too after logging in the user and redeeming the refresh token, I wasn't able to read the user profile using Graph API. Can someone please explain to me as to how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

AAD B2C tokens can not access Microsoft graph api. Customise the token such that it contains all the information you require in the first place.

Comment: What sort of customizations are you talking of? How can I create a user then without going about it with the microsoft way?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create users like an Admin would. Your native app needs to call an unauthenticated API. This API works just like it would if you wanted to create a user in AAD. Use client credentials at the API to get a token for MS Graph via your AAD Token Endpoint of the B2C directory. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api. The tokens issued by the B2C Token endpoint for B2C user authentication via User Flow or Custom Policy, cannot be used to call Graph API. Basically treat this scenario as if your B2C directory was an AAD.

Comment: Now to sign in the user, your B2C user flow or custom policy should be configured to output all the required claims rather than going to a /me endpoint, since B2C tokens (those issued via a User flow or custom policy) cannot call Graph API. Or any Microsoft APIs. Now there is no reason to use /me endpoint.